Requesting browser permissions for camera access with React / TypeScript
I'm trying to implement a function in my React web application that allows requesting permissions from the browser to access the user's camera, similar to how Google Meet does it. The first time a user visits my site, the browser displays a dialog with the options "Allow" or "Deny" for camera access.
I've developed a getVideoStream() function that utilizes the Permissions API and the MediaDevices API (getUserMedia) to request access to the camera.
async function getVideoStream() {
    try {
        const permissionStatus = await navigator.permissions.query({
            name: 'camera' as PermissionName
        });

        if (permissionStatus.state === 'denied') {
            console.error('Camera permission has been denied');
            return;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error checking camera permissions:', error);
        return;
    }

    let stream: MediaStream | null = null;

    try {
        stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting video stream:', error);
        return;
    }

    if (!stream || stream.getVideoTracks().length === 0) {
        console.error('Could not get a valid video track.');
        return;
    }
}



What is the problem you are facing ?

I am unable to access the permissions granted to the browser for the 'camera' media.
When I generate a request to access mediaDevices, I do not receive a response, or I do not get the typical modal or browser alert to grant camera permissions. Here is the link.

can u check if the permissions for the site has been already granted? i have used an implementation similar to this in the past https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/usePermission.ts and was working fine, maybe can refer this and try to exactly figure out whats going, also its better if u create a sandbox example for other to better help u

Hello, this is the snippet I'm using to validate and request camera permissions. However, I'm not getting the expected outcome.

When someone enters the web page, I expect to receive the camera permissions request.
If the user clicks "Deny" in the modal where camera permissions are assigned, I want the browser alert to reappear when clicking "Request Permissions" again.

CodeSandBox

could you please clear your browser data using "Ctrl+Shift+Delete" for Chrome and check if the issue is still there or not?
Actually, the permission prompt will only appear the first time the user visits your site or after they have reset their permissions. If the user has previously granted or denied camera access, the browser will remember their choice, and the prompt won't appear again unless the user clears their site data or changes their permissions manually.

I tried your code and its perfectly works for me.
const [isCameraAccessGranted, setIsCameraAccessGranted] = useState(false);

async function getVideoStream() {
        try {
            const permissionsStatus = await navigator.permissions.query({
                name: 'camera',
            });
            if (permissionsStatus.state === 'denied') {
                setIsCameraAccessGranted(false);
                return;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error checking camera permissions:', error);
        }
        let stream = null;
        try {
            stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
            console.log(stream);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error getting video stream', error);
        }
        if (!stream || stream.getVideoTracks().length === 0) {
            console.log('Could not get a valid video track.');
            return;
        } else {
            setIsCameraAccessGranted(stream.active);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (selected === 'scanBarcode') {
            getVideoStream();
        }
    }, [selected]);


Then you can conditionally render what you want after checking isCameraAccessGranted.
